# How can I deal with data that is on the format "Image + single number"?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, convolutional-neural-network

Let say I have a data set where every sample is an image of a landscape and a temperature associated with the landscape. How do I incorporate the temperature into my convolutional neural network for classifying if the data is e.g a winter or summer landscape? Can I simply add the temperature as a feature after the feature learning part of the network? I can not find similar questions but maybe this has a name that I am not aware of?

Comment: Append it near the top, before the final fully connected layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the convolutional part you will need to add a normal, dense layer. Concatenate it to this layer and add some more layers if necessary, to add more interactions between the temperature and the image. This wouldn't necessarily need to be too deep because it can learn to represent the image features in a way that it will combine nicely with the temperature already, hopefully.